# Opaque vs transparent to the observer?

Tags: differences, phrase-usage, semantics

When you want to describe that a change should be made in a manner that is not visible to the observer (in other words, the change should retain the current behavior of the system/process/application), do you use:

> [...] the change should be completely transparent to the user.

or

> [...] the change should be completely opaque to the user.

As a concrete example, consider this: a web application's optimization (improving performance) should be made in such a way that the end user doesn't notice at all that the underlying application code changed. There should be no visible effect or change in behavior, only in performance.

I can argue for either word.

If a change is *transparent*, it's not visible. But at the same time, *transparency* is usually used to mean that you operate in plain sight, in an open way that anyone can observe and supervise (see [Transparency (behavior)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_%28behavior%29)).

Or, if a change is *opaque*, then it's fully visible (physically speaking, it reflects light). But it could mean that the change is *opaque* in the meaning of a [Black box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box) — you have no knowledge of the internals (which is exactly what this change is about, too — you don't & shouldn't care about the underlying implementation of the optimization change).

(Not sure about my use of tags for this question.)

Comment: We only use ***transparent*** in such contexts. The allusion is to looking through something like ***glass*** (which is "transparent, clear", so you might not even be aware that there ***was*** glass in between your eyes and whatever you're looking at). Alternatively, ***invisible*** or even ***unnoticeable***, but never ***opaque***.

Comment: It should be invisible to the user.  (Virtually all products of computer geekdom are opaque to the user.)

Comment: This has been discussed over at ELL: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17693/what-is-the-correct-interpretation-of-transparent. The top answer suggests that computer technologists seem to have repurposed the word *transparent* to mean the opposite of what it had previously meant (i.e. *invisible* instead of *easily understood* or, as Merriam-Webster says, "characterized by visibility or accessibility of information especially concerning business practices"). My recommendation is to buck this trend and stop using *transparent*, where *invisible* or *undetected* would suffice.

Comment: Ok. before posting I did a search on google and english.SE, but not over on ELL. I never know which SE to use :).

Comment: Btw, would you say that this use of *transparent* only applies to technology, or is it being used everywhere now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "transparent" have contradictory meanings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/617336/does-transparent-have-contradictory-meanings)

Answer (score 1):

If the change is transparent to the user then it can't be seen.

Transparent - means you can't see it.

Opaque - means you can't see through it. As light doesn't penetrate. If you say the change is opaque then it can be seen.

I do understand your idea of using opaque to mean 'hidden or concealed'.

If you you say the change is opaque, though, it sounds weird. Normally, transparent is the word that's used.

However... I think a confusing factor here, is that there's a modern use of the word or a new creation of the word 'transparency', to mean 'allowing others to see through your process'. Which obviously is the opposite of what you want to convey!

So in my view transparency is the correct word, however - because of the modern use of the word to mean 'exposure of the process' it's rendered less suitable or less appropriate.

And so I suggest:

**Indistinguishable**

You could instead use 'indistinguishable' which means you cannot tell, or cannot distinguish, the difference - in this case, between the original, and the new version.

Example:
The backend system improvements are designed to be indistinguishable to the end-user.

Or you could use '**imperceptible**' - cannot be perceived.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/indistinguishable